# Does the set $\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c} x\\ y \end{array}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}|x\leq y\right\} $ span all of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Does the set$\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \ s.t\ x\leq y\right\} $ span all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I don't know because $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and then $\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is just a general vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because $x\leq y$.
and does it equals to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Please precise the operation involved when talking about groups.

Comment: why double brackets?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if the given set spans all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an $\mathbb{R}$ vector space?

Comment: @NoahSolomon yes

Comment: *Hint:* Try to find a basis.

Comment: “Group” is a technical term in algebra. What you have here is not a group, it’s a **set**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of "group" word is misleading here, especially with the question tagged group theory as well.

So let consider the vector space only question. $\mathbb R^2$ needs only two independent vectors to be spanned.

It is clear that $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are independent and both belong to your initial set, so these two vectors just by themselves span $\mathbb R^2$. A fortiori the whole set also does.

I could have taken $(1,1)$ as in azif00's answer, but this is just to show that even with $x<y$, the question remains mostly unaffected.

Comment: can you explain if $\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}|x\leq y\ \right\} =\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: No it is not equal, this set is a half plane (whose border is the line $y=x$). As a vector space it spans the whole plane, but as a set it is different.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be the span of the specified group. Fix an arbitrary $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Ix $x\leq y$ then clearly $(x,y) \in V$. If $x>y$ then $-x<-y$, so $(-x,-y) = -1(x,y) \in V$. So yes, it spans.

Comment: and does it equals to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @user75453 Well the span is equal to all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the set itself is of course not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your argument, but $\dbinom 11$ and $\dbinom 01$ are elements of $\bigg\{ \dbinom uv \in \mathbb R^2 : u \leq v \bigg\}$ such that $$\binom xy = x \dbinom 11 + (y-x) \dbinom 01$$ for every $\dbinom xy \in \mathbb R^2$.